# Android Studio says that Instant run is disabled because it doesn't have the right API level

Tags: android, android-studio, android-fragments, android-emulator, android-api-levels

I seem to be having another problem with updating my Android app to api 30. Right now I'm trying to test the app in an emulator with Android SDK 30 installed. However, I keep getting these error messages in the event log:

11:58 AM    Instant Run is disabled:
Instant Run requires that the Android SDK for the API level of the device you are deploying to is installed.
To use Instant Run, open SDK Manager and install the missing platform.

12:28 PM    Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf

12:28 PM    Emulator: added library vulkan-1.dll

1:15 PM Emulator: handleCpuAcceleration: feature check for hvf

1:15 PM Emulator: added library vulkan-1.dll

1:15 PM Emulator: C:\Users\Username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\emulator\qemu\windows-x86_64\qemu-system-x86_64.exe: error while loading state for instance 0x0 of device 'goldfish_pipe'

1:15 PM Emulator: deleteSnapshot: for default_boot

This is very frustrating since I've already downloaded Android API 30 to Android Studio and to the emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes all it requires is for you to clear the cache and restart the emulator.  You can also verify the api version on the emulator by logging the info to the console:

`Log.i("MSG", Integer.valueOf(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT)`

Comment: Ok, which console am I supposed to input this command?